# How to change class of <label> using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have following HTML code in my JSP page:

```
<label class="txt12Red">Label 1</label>
    <label class="txt12Red">Label 2</label>
<label class="txt12Red">Label 3</label>
```

I need to change the class of all labels with `class="txt12Red"` to `class="txt12"`. This will be done on some JavaScript event.

Comment: js please, update your post with js event,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just an example of an onclick event:

```
$("label").on("click", function() {
    $("label.txt12Red")
        .addClass("txt12")
        .removeClass("txt12Red");
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `toggleClass method` :

```
$("label").click(function() {
   $("label.txt12Red").toggleClass("txt12Red txt12");
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't change the class directly, but however you can remove the class you don't want then add the class you want.

```
function changeClass(oldClassName,newClassName){
$("label."+oldClassName).removeClass(oldClassName).addClass(newClassName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try out this one http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/ you could find more details